# Send end receive UDP in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, udp

I want to send a package from my computer to the unity app installed on my smartphone. I refer from this tutorial http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/simple-udp-implementation-send-read-via-mono-c.15900/ . The codes is very good when I run on unity virtual machine but when I change IP to my local IP (192.168.0.102). My phone can not receive data. Can you help me solve this problem. 
Thank you very much!

UDPSend.cs

```
/*

    -----------------------
    UDP-Send
    -----------------------
    // [url]http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb979228.aspx#ID0E3BAC[/url]

    // > gesendetes unter
    // 127.0.0.1 : 8050 empfangen

    // nc -lu 127.0.0.1 8050

        // todo: shutdown thread at the end
*/
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

public class UDPSend : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static int localPort;

    // prefs
    private string IP;  // define in init
    public int port;  // define in init

    // "connection" things
    IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint;
    UdpClient client;

    // gui
    string strMessage="";


    // call it from shell (as program)
    private static void Main()
    {
        UDPSend sendObj=new UDPSend();
        sendObj.init();

        // testing via console
        // sendObj.inputFromConsole();

        // as server sending endless
        sendObj.sendEndless(" endless infos \n");

    }
    // start from unity3d
    public void Start()
    {
        init();
    }

    // OnGUI
    void OnGUI()
    {
        Rect rectObj=new Rect(40,380,200,400);
        GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle();
        style.alignment = TextAnchor.UpperLeft;
        GUI.Box(rectObj,"# UDPSend-Data\n127.0.0.1 "+port+" #\n"
                + "shell> nc -lu 127.0.0.1  "+port+" \n"
                ,style);

        // ------------------------
        // send it
        // ------------------------
        strMessage=GUI.TextField(new Rect(40,420,140,20),strMessage);
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(190,420,40,20),"send"))
        {
            sendString(strMessage+"\n");
        }      
    }

    // init
    public void init()
    {
        // Endpunkt definieren, von dem die Nachrichten gesendet werden.
        print("UDPSend.init()");

        // define
        //IP="127.0.0.1";
        IP = "192.168.0.102";
        port=8051;

        // ----------------------------
        // Senden
        // ----------------------------
        remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), port);
        client = new UdpClient();

        // status
        print("Sending to "+IP+" : "+port);
        print("Testing: nc -lu "+IP+" : "+port);

    }

    // inputFromConsole
    private void inputFromConsole()
    {
        try
        {
            string text;
            do
            {
                text = Console.ReadLine();

                // Den Text zum Remote-Client senden.
                if (text != "")
                {

                    // Daten mit der UTF8-Kodierung in das Binärformat kodieren.
                    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

                    // Den Text zum Remote-Client senden.
                    client.Send(data, data.Length, remoteEndPoint);
                }
            } while (text != "");
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            print(err.ToString());
        }

    }

    // sendData
    private void sendString(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            //if (message != "")
            //{

            // Daten mit der UTF8-Kodierung in das Binärformat kodieren.
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

            // Den message zum Remote-Client senden.
            client.Send(data, data.Length, remoteEndPoint);
            //}
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            print(err.ToString());
        }
    }


    // endless test
    private void sendEndless(string testStr)
    {
        do
        {
            sendString(testStr);


        }
        while(true);

    }

}
```

UDPReceive.cs

```
/*

        -----------------------
        UDP-Receive (send to)
        -----------------------
        // [url]http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb979228.aspx#ID0E3BAC[/url]


        // > receive
        // 127.0.0.1 : 8051

        // send
        // nc -u 127.0.0.1 8051

    */
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

public class UDPReceive : MonoBehaviour {

    // receiving Thread
    Thread receiveThread;

    // udpclient object
    UdpClient client;

    // public
    // public string IP = "127.0.0.1"; default local
    public int port; // define > init

    // infos
    public string lastReceivedUDPPacket="";
    public string allReceivedUDPPackets=""; // clean up this from time to time!


    // start from shell
    private static void Main()
    {
        UDPReceive receiveObj=new UDPReceive();
        receiveObj.init();

        string text="";
        do
        {
            text = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        while(!text.Equals("exit"));
    }
    // start from unity3d
    public void Start()
    {

        init();
    }

    // OnGUI
    void OnGUI()
    {
        Rect rectObj=new Rect(40,10,200,400);
        GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle();
        style.alignment = TextAnchor.UpperLeft;
        GUI.Box(rectObj,"# UDPReceive\n127.0.0.1 "+port+" #\n"
                + "shell> nc -u 127.0.0.1 : "+port+" \n"
                + "\nLast Packet: \n"+ lastReceivedUDPPacket
                + "\n\nAll Messages: \n"+allReceivedUDPPackets
                ,style);
    }

    // init
    private void init()
    {
        // Endpunkt definieren, von dem die Nachrichten gesendet werden.
        print("UDPSend.init()");

        // define port
        port = 8051;

        // status
        print("Sending to 127.0.0.1 : "+port);
        print("Test-Sending to this Port: nc -u 127.0.0.1  "+port+"");


        // ----------------------------
        // Abhören
        // ----------------------------
        // Lokalen Endpunkt definieren (wo Nachrichten empfangen werden).
        // Einen neuen Thread für den Empfang eingehender Nachrichten erstellen.
        receiveThread = new Thread(
            new ThreadStart(ReceiveData));
        receiveThread.IsBackground = true;
        receiveThread.Start();

    }

    // receive thread
    private  void ReceiveData()
    {

        client = new UdpClient(port);
        while (true)
        {

            try
            {
                // Bytes empfangen.
                IPEndPoint anyIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
                byte[] data = client.Receive(ref anyIP);

                // Bytes mit der UTF8-Kodierung in das Textformat kodieren.
                string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

                // Den abgerufenen Text anzeigen.
                print(">> " + text);

                // latest UDPpacket
                lastReceivedUDPPacket=text;

                // ....
                allReceivedUDPPackets=allReceivedUDPPackets+text;

            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                print(err.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    // getLatestUDPPacket
    // cleans up the rest
    public string getLatestUDPPacket()
    {
        allReceivedUDPPackets="";
        return lastReceivedUDPPacket;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your phone and your computer need to be in the same LAN, and the firewall needs to allow the service and port.